# Can I tell saxon to figure out the XSLT version on its own?

Tags: saxon, command-line-tool

I have to run an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet with `saxonb-xslt` (which warns about 1.0 stylesheets) and an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with `saxon-xslt` (which wont work on 2.0 stylesheets). Is there a way to tell saxon: "Here is a stylesheet, figure out how to deal with it on your own."?

I want to keep my Makefiles as simple as possible and as warning-free as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this question hasn't been answered; you might find it more effective to ask Saxon-specific questions on the Saxon help list (accessible via the project on Sourceforge).

Generally these days I advise people to use a recent Saxon release (9.4) even for processing XSLT 1.0 code, in preference to using the old Saxon 6.5 processor. Yes, it produces a warning - unfortunately the XSLT 2.0 spec requires the warning - but you have to be doing something pretty strange to hit any compatibility problems. If you don't like the warning you can suppress it using -versionmsg:off.

But if you do want to select a different XSLT processor based on the version attribute in the stylesheet, you'll just have to code that logic into your script. This is easy enough if your script is written in an XML-oriented language such as XProc or xmlsh, it's a bit more tricky if you are using a general-purpose shell script.

Comment: My point was, warnings are there for a reason (at least in C). Interpreting an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet as 2.0 and simply suppressing the warning sounds potentially dangerous. If the spec requires a warning, there must be something that will go wrong (e.g. incompatibilities). I see you're involved with saxon, so I wonder why you cannot simply include both processors (for 1.0 and 2.0) in one tool and decide which one to run *after* you figured out the xstl version of the input you were provided?